# Component not rendering on state change

Tags: reactjs, react-table

I have a component which contains a react-table and a button.  It supposed to start with an empty table and the the user clicks on the button to add a row and enter data.

```
import React from "react";
import {Button, Row} from "react-bootstrap";
import {useTable} from "react-table";

export default function PlantDetail() {
    const [plants, setPlants] = React.useState([])

    const data = React.useMemo(() => plants, [plants])
    const addRow = () => {
        plants.push({"species_id": "10002", "name": "Maria", "weight": 15})
        setPlants(plants)
    }
    const columns = React.useMemo(
        () => [
            {
                Header: "Name", accessor: "name",
            },
            {Header: "Weight", accessor: "weight"},
        ],
        []
    )

    const {
        getTableProps,
        getTableBodyProps,
        headerGroups,
        rows,
        prepareRow,

    } = useTable({columns, data})


    return (<React.Fragment>
        <Row>
            <table {...getTableProps()}>
                <thead>
                {
                    headerGroups.map(headerGroup => (
                        <tr {...headerGroup.getHeaderGroupProps()}>
                            {
                                headerGroup.headers.map(column => (
                                    <th {...column.getHeaderProps()}>
                                        {column.render('Header')}
                                    </th>
                                ))}
                        </tr>
                    ))}
                </thead>
                <tbody {...getTableBodyProps()}>
                {
                    rows.map(row => {
                        prepareRow(row)
                        return (
                            <tr {...row.getRowProps()}>
                                {row.cells.map(cell => {
                                    return (
                                        <td {...cell.getCellProps()}>
                                            {cell.render('Cell')}
                                        </td>
                                    )
                                })}
                            </tr>
                        )
                    })}
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </Row>
        <Row>
            <Button onClick={addRow}>Button</Button>
        </Row>
    </React.Fragment>)
}
```

So I'm just focused on creating a new row which is why in this example I simply add a hard coded value.

However button doesn't cause a render. The data is added but the render does not happen.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're mutating state by using [`push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push).

This causes react to "miss" the state update and not re-render. When your state is an Object or Array, you need to pass a new instance on updates.

Below is a simplified example of how React determines if it should update:

```js
const state = [1,2];

function setState(newState) {
  if (state !== newState) {
    console.log('re-render');
  } else {
    console.log('skip');
  }
}

// Wrong
state.push(3);
setState(state);

// Right
setState(state.concat(4));
```

There's several solutions, but one would be `concat`.

```
setPlants(plants.concat({"species_id": "10002", "name": "Maria", "weight": 15}))
```

This will work since [`concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) does not mutate the original array but returns a new one.

Here's an example of the difference:

```js
const arr1 = [1,2,3];
const arr2 = [1,2,3];

arr1.push(4);

console.log('arr1', arr1);

const arr3 = arr2.concat(4);

console.log('arr2', arr2);

console.log('arr3', arr3);
```